# Icon drawable inside IconButton is black despite it being white

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-compose-card, android-compose-image

The `Icon` drawable inside the `IconButton` composable is black despite it being white. The picture below of the current setup shows the garbage can icon at the top right on an `alpha` background. How can I fix this issue?

[image]

```
@Composable
fun AppImage(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    imageUri: Uri = Uri.EMPTY,
    contentScale: ContentScale = ContentScale.None,
    contentDescription: String? = null,
    loadingImage: @Composable (SubcomposeAsyncImageScope.(AsyncImagePainter.State.Loading) -> Unit)? = null,
    successResult: @Composable (SubcomposeAsyncImageScope.(AsyncImagePainter.State.Success) -> Unit)? = null,
    errorResult: @Composable (SubcomposeAsyncImageScope.(AsyncImagePainter.State.Error) -> Unit)? = null
) {
    Card(
        modifier = Modifier
            .height(250.dp)
            .width(350.dp)
            .padding(15.dp)
            .clickable(
                indication = null,
                interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() }) {
            },
        elevation = 7.dp
    ) {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(16.dp)
                .wrapContentSize(Alignment.Center)
        ) {
            SubcomposeAsyncImage(
                model = imageUri,
                modifier = modifier,
                contentScale = contentScale,
                contentDescription = contentDescription,
                loading = loadingImage,
                success = successResult,
                error = errorResult
            )

            IconButton(
                onClick = {},
                modifier = Modifier
                    .clip(CircleShape)
                    .background(color = Color.Black.copy(alpha = 0.5f))
                    .align(Alignment.TopEnd)
                    .size(33.dp)
            ) {
                Icon(
                    painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_filled_delete_30),
                    contentDescription = "Delete Item Picture",
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .clickable(onClick = {
                        })
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can chanage color of drawable using tint property of Icon

```
@Composable
fun Icon(
    painter: Painter,
    contentDescription: String?,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    tint: Color = LocalContentColor.current.copy(alpha = LocalContentAlpha.current)
)
```

Comment: Not sure this works , but for me the following works  tint = Color.Unspecified as mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/q/75339047/377960