# Remove black tint from IconButton in jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-drawable, android-jetpack

I am using `IconButton` in code. I used drawable with different color. When I run the code it shows black think. So what is wrong in here?

```
IconButton(
    onClick = {  }
) {
    Icon(
        painter = painterResource(R.drawable.ic_menu),
        contentDescription = null,
    )
}
```

**Actual Output**

[image]

**Expected Output**

[image]

I am sharing my drawable file here

**ic_menu.xml**

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="20dp"
    android:height="4dp"
    android:viewportWidth="20"
    android:viewportHeight="4">
    <path
        android:fillColor="@color/aqua"
        android:fillType="evenOdd"
        android:pathData="M2,2m-2,0a2,2 0,1 1,4 0a2,2 0,1 1,-4 0" />
    <path
        android:fillColor="@color/aqua"
        android:fillType="evenOdd"
        android:pathData="M10,2m-2,0a2,2 0,1 1,4 0a2,2 0,1 1,-4 0" />
    <path
        android:fillColor="@color/aqua"
        android:fillType="evenOdd"
        android:pathData="M18,2m-2,0a2,2 0,1 1,4 0a2,2 0,1 1,-4 0" />
</vector>
```

Comment: Why don't you use `tint` parameter of `Icon` function?

Comment: Is it necessary to use tint option ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to pass `tint = Color.Unspecified` in `Icon` If you want to use the original icon color without any default tint.

Example:

```
Icon(
    painter = painterResource(R.drawable.ic_menu),
    tint = Color.Unspecified,
    contentDescription = null
 )
```

Based on the official docs, Icon uses the **default black tint** for all resources when you are not providing any tint.

[image: Icon]

As you can see it uses `LocalContentColor` Which is ***black by default***.

[image: LocalContentColor]